# How to get data from custom properties in UITestPropertyProvider

Tags: coded-ui-tests

According to the code sample on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx) any custom property data that you need to get out of your control should be in a semicolon delimited string in the `AccessibleObject`'s `Description` property. This does not seem right to me at all. This seems like just a quick and dirty trick to get it working. What is the correct way to get the value of properties from custom controls? And if this actually is how you're supposed to do it, then how are you supposed to set those properties using the `SetPropertyValue` method? The example in the link above just throws a `NotImplementedException` in `SetPropertyValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `IAccessible` interface has only a limited number of properties the best solution is to cram any extra information into the `Description` property (that's what they do at the company I work at, and our developers don't work quick and dirty :) ). To modify the return value of this property you have to implement the `Iaccessible` interface on your control. Or, since you only want to modify the `Description` property you only need to modify that property and leave the rest to the proxy (I'm not sure how this works exactly but there are tutorials for it on MSDN).

The `SetPropertyValue` method in the `UITestPropertyProvider` is for the `UItestControl`s. By overwriting it you can modify the way CUIT interacts with the control during playback. For example, if you overwrite `SetPropertyValue` for the Text property you can change the way CUIT types strings into the control.

Comment: How can you use a delimited string? This control's text property accepts any user input. Whatever character I use as a delimiter could be part of the value of the text so splitting the string would give in correct results.

Comment: There's no such parser that can't be screwed over if you use its special characters or tags against it (I boldly think so). You could try wrapping the text in tags, like `[Atr1]blablabla[Atr2]more blabla` then parse it accordingly. Of course if the user types `[Atrn]` in your control it messes things up but if the tags are indexed you can work around it. Now that I think about indexing the tags solves this problem. So my previous statement stands corrected.

Comment: After I went home I thought of something. I can convert the text to a base64 string to "hide" the delimiter character/string if someone uses it in the text property.